# Adding an XML Menu File Dynamically to NavigationView Android

Tags: android, android-navigationview

I have two XML menu files in my menu folder. I would like to add the menu xml file dynamically - in code, and not through the NavigationView element on the Activity layout file.

I have seen solutions where you add menu items to the menu. Is there a way of adding an xml file to the navigationview programmatically? Or will I have to add each menu item individually?